# Difference between redirectToAction() and View()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As I am new to ASP.NET MVC can anybody tell me the difference between `return RedirectToAction()` and `return View()`?

Answer (score 25):

`return View()` tells MVC to generate HTML to be displayed and sends it to the browser.

[`RedirectToAction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154.aspx) tells ASP.NET MVC to respond with a Browser redirect to a different action instead of rendering HTML.  The browser will receive the redirect notification and make another request for the new action.

An example ...

let's say you are building a form to collect and save data, your URL looks like `SomeEntity/Edit/23`.  In the Edit action you will do `return View()` to render a form with input fields to collect the data.

For this example let's say that on successful save of the data you want to display the data that has been saved. After processing the user's submitted data, if you do something like a `RedirectToAction("Index")` where Index is the action that will display the data.  The browser will get a HTTP 302 (temporary redirect) to go to `/SomeEntity/Index/23`.

Comment: RedirectToAction is also used to implement PRG pattern

Answer (score 17):

1. Return `View` doesn't make a new requests, it just renders the view
   without changing URLs in the browser's address bar.
2. Return `RedirectToAction` makes a new request and the URL in the browser's
   address bar is updated with the generated URL by MVC.
3. Return `Redirect` also makes a new request and the URL in the browser's address
   bar is updated, but you have to specify the full URL.
4. `RedirectToRoute` redirects to the specified route defined in the the
   route table.

Between `RedirectToAction` and `Redirect`, best practice is to use
    `RedirectToAction` for anything dealing with your application
    actions/controllers. If you use `Redirect` and provide the URL, you'll
    need to modify those URLs manually when you change the route table.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to all answers above, if you are using Implementing Validation using Data Annotation, use `return View()` instead of `RedirectToAction()`.

Validation message will not work using RedirectToAction as it doesn't get the model that is not valid and your validation message will not show as well on your view.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://devbloggies.blogspot.com/2019/07/difference-between-return-view-return-redirect-return-redirecttoaction-and-redirecttoroute-in-mvc.html) is simplest explanation of rendering view in mvc.

Comment: At least try to explain something in your answer.