# When do you use View() vs. RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

This [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521158/difference-between-redirecttoaction-and-view) sums up the basics of my question. The best answers there tells the difference between the two methods. I am looking for guidelines as to which method to use.

In short, I have an action in a controller which process a form and then display the results of the processing. When should I use `return View()` as opposed to `return RedirectToAction("FormResult")`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can really use either.  Generally speaking, though, after a form is posted you want to redirect so that refreshing the page doesn't cause the form to repost.  Sometimes, however, it's not feasible to copy state to the new page and your processing is idempotent so refresh wouldn't hurt anything.

It's not that there's a hard-and-fast rule.  You kind of have to weigh the pros and the cons.

Answer (score 30):

I would venture to say there is a hard and fast rule (well as much as there can be) - the [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). The standard with MVC (and the html helpers actually expect you to use this pattern) is:

1. post your data.
2. If there is an error (i.e. `ModelState.IsValid=false`) then `return View()` otherwise `return RedirectResult`.

If there was an error the HTML helpers will actually look at the posted values to redisplay as opposed to what you pass them by `View(model)` - again because the PRG pattern is 'supposed' to be what happened.

Comment: Outstanding answer!  `RedirectResult` requires `return new RedirectResult("url")` though so presumably something like `return RedirectToAction("Index")` is easier and cleaner.

Comment: This should be the top answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

1. Return View doesn't make a new requests, it just renders the view
2. without changing URLs in the browser's address bar.  Return
   RedirectToAction makes a new requests and URL in the browser's
   address bar is updated with the generated URL by MVC.
3. Return Redirect also makes a new requests and URL in the browser's address
   bar is updated, but you have to specify the full URL to redirect
4. Between RedirectToAction and Redirect, best practice is to use
   RedirectToAction for anything dealing with your application
   actions/controllers. If you use Redirect and provide the URL, you'll
   need to modify those URLs manually when you change the route table.
5. RedirectToRoute redirects to the specifies route defined in the the
   Route table.