# Property become NULL when redirecting to another action with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project in MVC asp.net programming in C#.

My `arena` class has 5 properties:

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int CharacterId { get; set; }
 public int Forfeit { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime Queued { get; set; }   
 public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
```

When I get a model of `Arena` from the database using this:

```
 var arenaModel = ctx.Arenas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Character.AccountId == currentUserId);
```

Nothing is null, there is a character, id is there, forfeit and queued.
But when I redirect to another action using this:

```
 return RedirectToAction("BattleNPC", arenaModel);
```

and using a breakpoint in the BattleNPC method

```
 public ActionResult BattleNPC(Arena model)
 {
     var character = model.Character; // <-- Null
 }
```

Suddenly the property for `Character` is null, I can still get see the other properties fine but `Character` become null.

Why is that? Can someone explain why `Character` becomes null. 
I know how to fix it, I just don't understand why it becomes null.

Comment: `Character` is `null` because internally the `RedirectToAction()` method generates query string values based on the `.ToString()` value of each property in your model. And for you last property, this returns `&Character="yourAssembly.Character"` which cannot be bound to tyeof `Character`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RedirectToAction` advices your browser to redirect to a new url. The model get's lost along the way since this the browser will only perform a new GET-Request. You can add parameters in a key-value form. This would be added to the URL

```
RedirectToAction('actionX', new { id = 123 })
```

Your Action would then fetch the DataObject based on the given id.

```
public ActionResult BattleNPC(int arenaId)
{
  var model = var arenaModel = ctx.Arenas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == arenaId);
  var character = model.Character; // <-- Null
}
```

Or, if you action is located in the same controller, simply return using view()

see: [When do you use View() vs. RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775752/when-do-you-use-view-vs-redirecttoaction) 
or: [Difference between redirectToAction() and View()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521158/difference-between-redirecttoaction-and-view)