# ViewBag data not transfer to View in asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

some resin **viewBag**  data is not going to view. I can't understand why

my **controller ActionResult** is

```
[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult LoginSeller(string userId, string password)
    {

     int result= db.sellers.Where(p => p.userId == userId && p.password == password).Count();
     if (result != 1)
     {

          return View("ErrorLogin");
     }
     else
     {


         return View("LoginSuccess", new { sellerid = userId });
     }

    }
    public ActionResult LoginSuccess(string sellerid)
    {

        ViewBag.sessinoid = sellerid.ToString(); 
        return View();
    }
```

and my `LoginSuccess` view is

```
<h2>LoginSuccess</h2><span id="sellerid">@ViewBag.sessinoid</span>&nbsp;span id="logoutseller">@Html.ActionLink("LogOut","SellerCookiesDelete","Product") </span>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('the value is'+$("#sellerid").text() == "");
    if ($("#sellerid").text() == "") {
        $("#logoutseller").css({ 'display': 'none' });
    }

})
```

when control redirect to **LoginSuccess** page then showing `false` in alert box and `sellerid` span showing blank(empty) but why i can't understand.

Comment: `return View("LoginSuccess", new { sellerid = userId });` does not call the `LoginSuccess()` method. It just return the `LoginSuccess.cshtml` view. You need `return RedirectToAction("LoginSuccess", new { sellerid = userId });`

Comment: yes it work fine , thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: which type of difference haveing between `return View()` and `return RedirectToAction()`

Comment: [Difference between RedirectToAction() and View()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521158/difference-between-redirecttoaction-and-view)